# Access parts within AsyncDirective after setValue call

Tags: lit, lit-html

Is there any way for an `AsyncDirective` to access its rendered parts after a `setValue` call?

My directive's `update` method calls `super.update` which triggers the `render` method, but I need a method that's called after the `setValue` method call has been processed, because `update` is not called for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to hold a reference to the part within the directive class?

```
class MyDirective extends AsyncDirective {
  currentPart: Part;

  update(part, args) {
    this.currentPart = part;
    return this.render(...args);
  }

  render(promise) {
    promise.then((value) => {
      this.setValue(value);
      // do something with `this.currentPart` ?
    });
    return 'pending';
  }
  
}
```

Alternatively maybe you can add a `MutationObserver` to the element with the part instead so you can detect whatever change `setValue` has caused.

Comment: I also noticed that, after calling `super.update` in my `update` method, the `part` argument is updated, which may be useful to others that find this question in the future.